# Refresh/ reload the uipicker

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, reload

Hii,

I add the uipicker on a view. and that view i am showing on the different textbox begin editing event. and i want to fill the uipicker from the different datasources on the different textbox editing event. so i want to refresh or reload the data on uipicker view. so plz suggest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The picker will ask it's dataSource for new information every time `reloadAllComponents` is called. You can also specify a single component by calling `reloadComponent:` with the integer index of the component you want to reload.

All this can be easily found in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/reloadAllComponents).